# opencv python mirror only non zero pixels of the image

Tags: python, opencv

[image: matplotlib of source image I want to mirror]
Hello, after applying an affine rotation around some center point I want to mirror this image  but only considering the non zero pixels (i.e. not black) and then cv2.vconcat both. How could I do that the optimal way? If I mirror current image with x axis I get a black hall between both and wrong orientation of mirror image see second figure: [image: concat with wrong mirror image].

I suggest that mirror with respect not to the image frame but object frame should be considered but don't know which function does it.
The result should be similar to the following image:[image: good image]